# Slow starting Mac OS X

Tags: performance

My Mac OS X started taking up to 1 minute or so to get from the time I press the power button to where I enter my password. After I enter my password everything goes just fine. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks Craig

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you select a startup disk in system preferences. I had this problem, that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

-EDIT- oops, first time posting here and I just noticed this was asked many years ago

It might be that your Mac is having difficulty finding the start up disk.

Try resetting the NVRAM.   https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063